# Showing odd numbers

Tags: pgfplots

How can I show the odd numbers on the `xticklabels`?
[image]

> **CODE**:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,
    positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\linewidth}



\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{performance.data}
    x    A       B         C        D        E         F 
    0.01 0.9126  0.9126   0.9313   0.9494   0.9524   0.9462 
    0.02 0.8872  0.8872   0.8980   0.9044   0.9014   0.8966
    0.03 0.8713  0.8713   0.8747   0.8767   0.8737   0.8722
    0.05 0.8549  0.8549   0.8552   0.8541   0.8538   0.8532
    0.09 0.8710  0.8710   0.8700   0.8687   0.8676   0.8667
    0.10 0.8782  0.8782   0.8771   0.8751   0.8740   0.8738
    0.20 0.9301  0.9301   0.9281   0.9275   0.9269   0.9271
\end{filecontents}
\decimalpoint


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    grid = none,
    legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)}, anchor=south east, draw=black},
%   legend cell align=left,         
%   legend pos=north east,
    xmin=0.000499999999999999, xmax=0.2095,
    ylabel={RMSE},
    xlabel={$\lambda$},
    %
    xticklabel style={font=\small,
        /pgf/number format/fixed},  
    yticklabel style={font=\small},
    %
    every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1.2pt},
    %
    mark size=1.3pt,
    cycle list={
        {blue,mark=*},
        {black,mark=*},
        {red,mark=*},
        {green,mark=*},
        {orange,mark=*},
        {cyan,mark=*},% <-- don't add a comma here
    },
    ]
    \addplot    table [y=A] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{20 f}
    \addplot    table [y=B] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{40 f}
    \addplot    table [y=C] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{60 f}
    \addplot    table [y=D] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{100 f}
    \addplot    table [y=E] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{150 f}
    \addplot    table [y=F] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{200 f}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming you mean "showing the odd numbers in the `xticklabels` *as well*" you could simply add `xtick distance=0.1` to the `axis` options.

Comment: When I do what you say, it only shows the values 0.1 and 0.2, all the others are gone.

Comment: Perhaps he meant 0.01?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I tried it, but it does not work either :(

Comment: try `xtick={0.01,0.03,...,0.21},`?

Comment: Of course I meant `xtick distance=0.01` which works perfectly fine for me. But then the `xticklabels` overlap ... Again, I assume that you want to show the even ***and*** the odd numbers and not ***only*** the odd numbers. In the latter case you should use the suggestion of nidhin.

Comment: @nidhin You nailed it! It did work! Thanks!

Comment: @StefanPinnow Should I close it / delete?

Comment: I suggest that either @nidhin writes an answer or we close it as a duplicate, which -- I guess -- will be easy to find, because you are not the first one, who asked this (or at least very very similar) question.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Okay then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

You can mention the `xticks` manually like this:

```
xtick={0.01,0.03,...,0.20},
```

so that only odd ticks will be shown.

Result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\linewidth}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{performance.data}
    x    A       B         C        D        E         F 
    0.01 0.9126  0.9126   0.9313   0.9494   0.9524   0.9462 
    0.02 0.8872  0.8872   0.8980   0.9044   0.9014   0.8966
    0.03 0.8713  0.8713   0.8747   0.8767   0.8737   0.8722
    0.05 0.8549  0.8549   0.8552   0.8541   0.8538   0.8532
    0.09 0.8710  0.8710   0.8700   0.8687   0.8676   0.8667
    0.10 0.8782  0.8782   0.8771   0.8751   0.8740   0.8738
    0.20 0.9301  0.9301   0.9281   0.9275   0.9269   0.9271
\end{filecontents}
\decimalpoint


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    grid = none,
    legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)}, anchor=south east, draw=black},
%   legend cell align=left,         
%   legend pos=north east,
    xmin=0.000499999999999999, xmax=0.2095,
    ylabel={RMSE},
    xlabel={$\lambda$},
    %
    xtick={0.01,0.03,...,0.20},
    xticklabel style={font=\small,
        /pgf/number format/fixed},  
    yticklabel style={font=\small},
    %
    every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1.2pt},
    %
    mark size=1.3pt,
    cycle list={
        {blue,mark=*},
        {black,mark=*},
        {red,mark=*},
        {green,mark=*},
        {orange,mark=*},
        {cyan,mark=*},% <-- don't add a comma here
    },
    ]
    \addplot    table [y=A] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{20 f}
    \addplot    table [y=B] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{40 f}
    \addplot    table [y=C] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{60 f}
    \addplot    table [y=D] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{100 f}
    \addplot    table [y=E] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{150 f}
    \addplot    table [y=F] {performance.data};
    \addlegendentry{200 f}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```